# How to Display Image name in Label on hovering over the image

Tags: css, image, hover, label, zooming

I have eight images which zooms to 10 times when i hover over it. now i want to display the name of the image hovered (i.e alt="a" for the first image) in separate label on the top of the page. how to do it using css ??

```
<div class="positioner11">
<a class="slide" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a1" src="Insta/1.jpg" alt="a" /></a>
<a class="slide" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a2" src="Insta/2.jpg" alt="b" /></a>
<a class="slide" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a3" src="Insta/3.jpg" alt="c" /></a>
<a class="slide" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a4" src="Insta/4.jpg" alt="d" /></a>
<a class="slide" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a1" src="Insta/5.jpg" alt="e" /></a>
<a class="slide" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a2" src="Insta/6.jpg" alt="f" /></a>
<a class="slide" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a3" src="Insta/7.jpg" alt="g" /></a>

<a class="slide last" aria-haspopup="true"><img class="a5" src="Insta/8.jpg" alt="h" />       </a>

</div>

.positioner11 {position:absolute; left:0; top:576px;}

.slide {display:block; border:0; text-decoration:none; float:left; border-right:1px     solid #fff;}
.last {border:0;}
.slide img {display:block; border:0; width:50px; height:50px; cursor:pointer;
-webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
-moz-transition-duration: .7s; 
-o-transition-duration: .7s;
transition-duration: .7s;
}
.slide:hover img 
{
width:500px;
height:500px;

}
```

Comment: We'll need to see your HTML/CSS to answer this question ..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post some code so we can see what you have so far.

Comment: Hi user####### and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq in order to help StackOverflow users to help you. Otherwise, this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and/or not useful and might need some moderator attention to be salvage to waste. --> Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example:

```
$('ul li img').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('opacity','.5');
        var a = $(this).attr('alt');
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="title">' + a + '</div>');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('opacity','1');
        $(this).next().remove('.title');
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgKne/